# JWT not expiring in nestjs application even after setting expiresIn value

Tags: jwt, nestjs, passport.js

This is what my auth.module.ts looks like:

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";
import { JwtModule } from "@nestjs/jwt";
import { PassportModule } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import appConfig from "src/config/app.config";
import devConfig from "src/config/dev.config";
import stagConfig from "src/config/stag.config";
import { User } from "src/entities/entity/user.entity";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
import { JwtStrategy } from "./passport-strategies/jwt-strategy";
import { LocalStrategy } from "./passport-strategies/local-strategy";



@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      load: [appConfig, devConfig, stagConfig],
      ignoreEnvFile: true,
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
       User
    ]),
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
        imports: [ConfigModule],
        useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
          // secret: configService.get<string>('jwt.secret'),
          secret: process.env.TOKEN_KEY,
          signOptions: { expiresIn: 30 }
        }),
        inject: [ConfigService]
      }),
  ],
  providers: [
      AuthService, 
      LocalStrategy, 
      JwtStrategy
  ],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

As you can see I have set `signOptions: { expiresIn: 30 }` but when I analyze the token it has no expiration parameter and does not expire.

I am using https://jwt.io/#encoded-jwt to analyze the token:

[image: This is a screenshot of the jwt]

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass the **expiresIn** value as string and mention **s for seconds** like this

```
 JwtModule.register({
      secret: jwtConstants.secret,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '60s' },
    }),
```

Do let me know if this works!

Comment: No, this does not work. `signOptions: { expiresIn: 60 }` this should also work but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem. search `ignoreExpiration` flag. Here's my problem
e:

```
@Injectable()
export class JWTStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(
    readonly configService: ConfigService,
    private userService: UserService,
  ) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromHeader(
        configService.get('API_ACCESS_TOKEN_HEADER'),
      ),
      ignoreExpiration: true, // *** FIXME: here
      secretOrKey: configService.get('API_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET'),
    });
  }
...
```

Here is type:

```
export interface StrategyOptions {
    secretOrKey?: string | Buffer | undefined;
    secretOrKeyProvider?: SecretOrKeyProvider | undefined;
    jwtFromRequest: JwtFromRequestFunction;
    issuer?: string | undefined;
    audience?: string | undefined;
    algorithms?: string[] | undefined;
    ignoreExpiration?: boolean | undefined;
    passReqToCallback?: boolean | undefined;
    jsonWebTokenOptions?: VerifyOptions | undefined;
}
```

The `ignoreExpiration` used, https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/master/verify.js#L147

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

set your value in string like this:

```
JwtModule.register({secret: 'your-secret-key', signOptions : { expiresIn : '30d'}}) # for 30 days
```

also you can set the expiresIn value in calling sign method in jwtService

```
    jwtService.sign({Payload, {expiresIn: '10d', secret: ...})
```

if you don't set an expiration time when signing a JWT token, the token will not expire and can be used indefinitely.